# Safari Caching GET request even with disabled cache

Tags: http, caching, safari

I have set all headers that I know of to disable caching (even disabling ETAG) on my server, yet Safari still occasionally (about 50% times) caches my requests.

## Workflow

I am implementing oauth 1, so:

1. Browser makes `GET /api/user` request
2. Server returns 405
3. Browser redirects to 3rd party website to authenticate
4. Browser is redirected to `api/callback` which stores some info into cookie.
5. Browser is redirected back to original route.
6. Browser makes `GET /api/user` request which should be successful, however it gets 405 served from disk cache instead.

## Request summary from Safari Network Inspector

### Summary

**URL:** `http://localhost:3000/api/user`

**Status:** `405 Method Not Allowed`

**Source:** `Disk Cache`

### Request

No request, served from the disk cache.

### Response

**Transfer-Encoding:** `Identity`

**Content-Type:** `application/json; charset=utf-8`

**Pragma:** `no-cache`

**Cache-Control:** `private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0`

**Vary:** `Cookie, Accept-Encoding`

**Date:** `Wed, 23 Jan 2019 11:34:23 GMT`

**Content-Encoding:** `gzip`

**Expires:** `Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT`

**Connection:** `close`

**x-powered-by:** `Express`

### Conclusion

I have no idea what's wrong and I will greatly appreciate any help. My
Safari version is `12.0.2`. I wasn't able to replicate this issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Vary: *`. This magically solved my problem.

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068353/1364158

Alternatively, you can really force browser to load a new version of request by including some meaningless random query arg in your url, e.g. `/api/user?ts=18284`

Comment: Using `Vary: *` doesn't do anything for me... I'm forced to empty the cache manually.